# Loading project-specific Elisp script automatically

Tags: directory-local-variables

I have a project I am working on which contains custom file extensions (`.set`) for which I would like to write my own mode for. However, I want this mode to exist only within the context of the project.

What I've done so far was to write a `elisp/set-process.el` in the project directory, which looks something like this:

```
(defun process-set ()
   <call external program with current buffer>)

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'process-set)
```

The intention here is that every time I save a `.set` file inside the project directory, I will call a precompiled program to process its contents.

Now, every time I work on the project (and specifically the `.set` files) I call `M-: (load-file "elisp/set-process.el")`, and then edit away. This works well enough, but I would like to automate this process so that I don't have to load the script every time. I've read that I need to edit my `.dir-locals.el`, but I'm not sure how I could do it so that it could work as described. I was thinking maybe a custom mode is in order, but I would not know how to "load" it every time I am inside the directory.

My current `.dir-locals.el` is unchanged and looks like this:

```
((c++-mode . ((eval . (let ((project-include-dirs '("include" "ext/include"))
                (project-root-dir (expand-file-name (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")))
                (final-include-dirs ()))
            (while project-include-dirs
              (let ((incdir ""))
                (setq incdir (concat project-root-dir (car project-include-dirs)))
                (push incdir final-include-dirs)
                (setq project-include-dirs (cdr project-include-dirs))))
            (setq flycheck-clang-include-path final-include-dirs)
            (setq flycheck-clang-args '("-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic"))
            (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++20"))))))
```

If it isn't very clear yet, my understanding of Elisp is still very basic, so I apologize if I made some glaring mistakes, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're already doing want you want. You can do an `(eval . (load-file "elisp/set-process.el"))` in your `.dirs-local.el`. Although if your `elisp/set-process.el` is already "mode-like", _I'd_ make it a mode, and just associated it with that specific project's `.set` files via `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @nega Thanks for the direction. The first option seems like something I can do. Indeed, the link you shared does more or less solve what I need.

Comment: @nega Upon further examination, this does not work as well as I hoped. `dir-locals.el` is read every time I open a `.cpp` file, and I need it to be read only once to load the custom file.